# Can I use the Foursquare API to find all the public profile pictures at a venue?

Tags: api, foursquare, photos

I am interested in pulling all the public profile pictures of people that have recently checked in at a venue to show in a side list view, somewhat as a way to represent the popularity of the place, and was wondering if this is doable through their API.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `venue` endpoint doesn't give you detailed historical access to who has checked in there. It collapses this information into `stats` field, which gives you a total number of checkins at the venue and the total number of users that have checked in to the venue.

You can get close to what you are looking for by using the data provided by the `hereNow` field. This tells you who is 'currently' checked in to the venue, splitting the users into `friends` and `others`.

Full details about the `venue` endpoint below:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue